# Debian Squeeze: how to find out if RabbitMQ is installed?

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, rabbitmq

According to the RabbitMQ docs, the RabbitMQ server is already installed on Debian 6 Squeeze.

> rabbitmq-server is included in Debian since 6.0 (squeeze) and in Ubuntu since 9.04.

I tried to start it via SSH and *invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start* but realized that there is no rabbitmq-server in init.d. - *rabbitmqctl status* also is unknown. I also could not find it with *dpkg --get-selections*.

I have to admit that I am new to Linux, but could it be possible that there is no rabbitmq server preinstalled? Or maybe I am looking in the wrong places?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"rabbitmq-server is included in Debian since 6.0 (squeeze) and in Ubuntu since 9.04"* means they are available in their respective repositories not installed by default in default installation procedure.

You need to run

```
apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

to install

Comment: Thanks! The whole sentence is: _rabbitmq-server is included in Debian since 6.0 (squeeze) and in Ubuntu since 9.04. However, the versions included are often quite old._ Especially because of the second part of the sentence I assumed it is really installed. So they mean the repository is a little bit out of date?

Comment: yeah official repo might contain old version to maintain compatibilities with the libraries that comes with the distribution

Answer (score 1):

rabbitmq-server is not installed by default. What

> rabbitmq-server is included in Debian since 6.0 (squeeze) and in Ubuntu since 9.04.

Means is that you can do

```
apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

and that will install rabbitmq-server. You will not need to add any additional repositories.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to use such an old version of RabbitMQ. You can go here http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html and download the Ubuntu/Debian version, and then once the .deb file is downloaded, run

```
dpkg -i rabbitmq-server_2.8.4-1_all.deb
```

There are so many performance improvements and bug fixes that it does not make sense to use the old, old versions that exist in most Linux repositories.

If you don't already have Erlang installed (RabbitMQ runs on the Erlang VM) then the easiest way to do it is to follow the instructions from Bash here: http://wiki.basho.com/Installing-Erlang.html

P.S. it is even easier to just install the Riak binary package with Erlang included and just not use Riak. Or use the ESL repository with apt-get http://www.erlang-solutions.com/section/132/download-erlang-otp and yes they do have a Squeeze version in there.

Comment: But installing a static package with `dpkg` will basically leave you at that version forever, unless you periodically do a manual check for a new version and copy that package into place.  Adding an Apt repository which receives updates to the package periodically is vastly superior in the long run.